# Behaviour of $L^1$ and $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

In another proof I stumbled over the following question.

Let $(e_n)$ be an ONB of $L^2$ on a compact domain and $f \in L^1.$(this is the point here, $f$ is a priori not in $L^2$).So we have $L^2 \subset L^1$. Now, we have $\langle f, e_n \rangle =0$ for $n \ge 5$ and $\langle f,e_i \rangle$ for $i \in \{1,...,4\}$ exists and is finite.

Does this imply that $f \in span(e_1,...,e_4)$?

In case that this is true, maybe a density argument could lead to something, I would say, but this is really the only idea I have.

Comment: Why do we have $L^2 \subset L^1$? $$\int_\Omega |f| = \int_\Omega |f| \chi_\Omega \le ||f||_{L^2(\Omega)} |\Omega|^{1/2}$$ So I'd expect an inclusion the other way round.

Comment: @Thomas you just proved $L^2 \subset L^1.$

Comment: How do you know the integrals $\langle f, e_n\rangle$ exist?

Comment: It's true in the Fourier series case.

Comment: @zhw yes, actually I have the Fourier series case in mind, so $e_n$ are the complex exponetnials. do you know a proof of this?

Comment: @T.A.E. because $f$ is given and the inner-products all exist.

Comment: @wewasss : Produce a function $g \in L^{1}$ for which $(g,e_n)=0$ for all $n$. What would be the conclusion for the exponentials?

Comment: @T.A.E. it is not for all exponentials, just for almost all of them. Sorry, I think I don't get your hint completely, would you mind elaborating a little bit?

Comment: @wewasss : Find $a_n$ so that $g=f-\sum_{n=1}^{4}a_n e_n$ satisfies $\langle g, e_n\rangle = 0$ for all $n$. $g \in L^1$. What can you say about $g$?

Comment: Ah, nice, that's much simpler than what I did.

Comment: @T.A.E. $g$ is zero, because $L^2$ is dense? If I pick the Fourier coefficients as $a_n$?

Comment: @T.A.E.if $g$ is non-zero then there is a sequence $f_n$ of non-zero $L^2$ functions converging to $g$ in $L^1$-norm. Since the $f_n$ have a proper Fourier representation, we can approximate $g$ by a sequence of Fourier series which contradicts the "$g$ is orthogonal to all the $e_n$" property.

Comment: @wewasss : There are always problems dealing with $L^1$ because the Fourier series does not always converge in $L^{1}$ to the original function. However, if $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-inx}f(x)dx=0$ for all $n$ where $f \in L^{1}$, then it is true that $f=0$ a.e.. This result is not obvious, and there are several proofs out there. Personally, I like the Fejer kernel or the Poisson kernel that zhw used. But there are nice ones that use complex analysis to show that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{inx}d\mu(x)=0$ for a finite complex measure and all $n$ implies $\mu=0$. Your original context was too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof for the Fourier series case, $L^2([0,2\pi])$: Here we take $e_n(x) = e^{inx}, n \in \mathbb {Z}.$ Suppose $f\in L^1([0,2\pi])$ and $\langle  f,e_n  \rangle = 0, n \in \mathbb {Z}\setminus \{1,2,3,4\}.$ Poisson integral theory says

$$P_r[f](t) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb {Z}}\hat {f}(n)r^{|n|}e^{int}$$

converges to $f$ in $L^1$ as $r\to 1^-.$ But the sum above is the sum only over $n=1,2,3,4$ and the limit of this in $L^1$ is clearly $\sum_{n=1}^{4}\hat {f}(n)e^{int}.$ Hence $f$ equals this last sum.

Comment: what is Poisson integral theory?

Comment: You could replace the Poisson kernel with the Fejer kernels if you like.

Comment: @wewasss I'll leave this answer, but T.A.E.'s comment above suggests a better way to go.

Comment: do you know if my response to T.A.E.'s comment is correct?

Comment: Well $g\in L^1$ and all of $g$'s Fourier coefficients are $0.$ This implies $g=0.$ Do you know this result?

Comment: actually no, I am completely new to fourier analysis. is my denseness argument wrong?

Comment: if $g$ is non-zero then there is a sequence $f_n$ of non-zero $L^2$ functions converging to $g$ in $L^1$-norm. Since the $f_n$ have a proper Fourier representation, we can approximate $g$ by a sequence of Fourier series which contradicts the "$g$ is orthogonal to all the $e_n$" property.